# How to download multipule types stream of data and store it to client location

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to download multipule stream of data and save it to client  location.(Without showing open/save dialog box).

Please suggest appropriate solution.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: "I need to download multipule stream of data and save it to client location."  Viruses?

Answer (score 0):

File Download stream is controlled by browser. It depends on the browser to whether show file dialog or not. we cann't change that behaviour.

Comment: But can be force download the file on purticular location.